# Delayed Priority Rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp, priority-queue

I am facing a scenario where every message in the queue should be consumed after a delay that is achievable using TTL and Dead Letter Exchange in RabbitMQ but when a max TTL will be at the head than no other messages will be consumed.

I want to achieve that every message in the queue gets consumed after it's delay irrespective of its position in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on TTL and the dead-letter exchange you can use the [delayed-message-exchange](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange). With the delayed-message-exchange, the message is published to the queue only when its TTL expires. Consuming every message in the queue will require to add more consumers to the queue.